# R: Print Plot.ly into RMarkdown HTML from within a function

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, plotly

I have a document that loads some files, processes them, then prints the Plot.ly plots into the document. Everything works, except for trying to call the plotting function within another function, or a loop. Here is the structure of my code:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=TRUE}
my_plotly_function <- function(my_dataframe, ... ){
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("plotly"))

    my_plot <- plot_ly(data = my_dataframe, x = Column1, y = Column2, mode = "markers")
    return(my_plot)
}

sample_file_list <- c("sample4_control.tsv", "sample4_sample5.tsv", "sample5_control.tsv")


# this works
my_plotly_function(read.delim(sample_file_list[1],header = TRUE,sep = '\t'))

# this doesn't work
for(i in seq_along(sample_file_list)){
    my_plotly_function(read.delim(sample_file_list[i],header = TRUE,sep = '\t'))
}

# this does not work either
for(i in seq_along(sample_file_list)){
    print(my_plotly_function(read.delim(sample_file_list[i],header = TRUE,sep = '\t')))
}


# this also does not work
for(i in seq_along(sample_file_list)){
    my_plot <- my_plotly_function(read.delim(sample_file_list[i],header = TRUE,sep = '\t'))
    print(my_plot)
}
```
````

Any ideas? I know that some plots need to be `print`'d when used within a function or a loop, but Plot.ly does not seem to be working like this, it only seems to work when the Plot.ly object is returned directly into the document. So far, I have not figured out a way to use this without hard-coding it into the document, which is not ideal.

Comment: Try a function which returns a list: `Map(function(x,y,z) my_plotly_function(x,header = y, sep = z), sample_file_list, TRUE, '\t')`

Comment: I tried this, and while it works in RStudio, knitting the RMD document gives no plot ouput in the HTML. In fact I looked inside the HTML source and the plot is simply not there. I can see source code for javascript elements of other aspects of the document, but not these plots.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. After looking around for a solution and not finding one I came up with one of my own. It's a bit of a hack but it works:

1) set the plotly objects to a global var from within the function via <<-. I had more than one plotly object per functions so returning them didn't work (I tried).
2) unroll the loop (in my case feasible since there were only 5 iterations)
3) call the global plot var

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way round this that is related to this [post](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/273#issuecomment-195611009).

A slight change to the example given in the post to allow for function calls of `plot_ly` would be,

```
library(plotly)
plot_plotly <- function(x) plot_ly(x=x)
l <- htmltools::tagList()
for (i in 1:3) {
  l[[i]] <- plot_plotly(rnorm(10))
}
l
```

The key thing is using `htmltools::tagList` and saving the plotly graphs to this list and then printing it.